# How to copy sheets with certain tab color from one workbook to another?

Tags: excel, vba

I have several Workbooks where there are several sheets that have Tab color with RGB code (0,255,0) i.e. completely green so I need to copy only these sheets to ActiveWorkbook without opening workbooks containing these green sheets

```
Sub Copy_Green_Sheets()
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim ws As Worksheet

If ws.Tab.Color = RGB(0, 255, 0) Then
         Set wb = Workbooks("Target workbook")
         For Each ws In Workbooks("source workbook").Worksheets
         ws.Copy After:=wb.Sheets(wb.Sheets.Count)
         Next ws
End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Option Explicit

Sub DoItForAllWorkbooks()
    Dim myWorkbook As Workbook
    Dim myWbFullNames(100) As String
    Dim iCt As Integer

    ' You might to want to create such a list with Excel:
    '="'        myWbFullNames("&B3&") = ""C:\mySpecialFolder\myFile0"&B3&".xlsx"""

    myWbFullNames(1) = "C:\mySpecialFolder\myFile01.xls"
    myWbFullNames(2) = "C:\mySpecialFolder\myFile02.xls"
    myWbFullNames(3) = "C:\mySpecialFolder\myFile03.xls"
    myWbFullNames(4) = "C:\mySpecialFolder\TabColor4.xlsx"
    myWbFullNames(5) = "C:\mySpecialFolder\myFile05.xls"

    For iCt = 1 To 5
        Workbooks.Open myWbFullNames(iCt)
        Set myWorkbook = ActiveWorkbook
        Call Copy_Green_Sheets_NEW(ActiveWorkbook)
        myWorkbook.Close
    Next iCt
End Sub

Sub Copy_Green_Sheets_NEW(SourceWorkbook as workbook)
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set wb = Workbooks("Target workbook")
    'For Each ws In Workbooks("source workbook").Worksheets --- OLD
    For Each ws In SourceWorkbook.Worksheets
        If ws.Tab.Color = RGB(0, 255, 0) Then
            ws.Copy After:=wb.Sheets(wb.Sheets.Count)
        End If
    Next ws
End Sub
```

Comment: What needs to be in "source workbook"? There are many workbooks containing green sheets

Comment: Are all the workbooks open? Or are they in a certain folder?

Comment: They are in a certain folder

Comment: I've updated the code to include a call from different workbooks.

Comment: Thanks! It seems to be working but it never stops and keeps creating copies of these sheets, like 2nd (2), 3rd (3), 4th (4).... etc. Maybe it should stop loop somewhere on completion?