# Looping vlookup through predefined named range in multiple sheets

Tags: excel, vba

So I've been solving this problem of mine for a couple days already.
Basically, I have multiple green sheets (my source sheets) and one main sheet (master sheet), the problem I'm working on has to do with looping through these green sheets in order to pull certain information from them and put it on certain columns in my master sheet.
Here's the layout of one of these green sheets for better understanding:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/3rnjr.jpg 
I'm sorry for the links, cant add images yet
You can see that these green sheets consist of multiple boxes which can differ in size from sheet to sheet. Some of the values I need to retrieve are fixed in the same cell address for all green sheets so I have no problem getting them to the master sheet. But there are some cases like this:
 https://i.stack.imgur.com/5A01h.jpg
Assumption box contains information that I need to lookup and pull it to Main sheet. In essence, this box can take up vertically any space so that address for values of payroll, tax and miscellaneous expenditures changes.
I came up with the idea of giving these boxes in all green sheets name "Assumptions" like seen in the image above. So the questions is how do I lookup 3rd column of this named box and pull it to main sheet?
Here's Main sheet structure:
 https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cd6KY.jpg

My code so far:

```
Sub CombiningSheets()
    Dim p_value, cst_value, m_value As Long
    Dim p, cst, m As String
    p = "payroll"
   cst = "consolidated social tax"
    m = "miscellaneous expenditures"



With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Main")
    For Each wsheet In ThisWorkbook.Sheets


        If wsheet.Name <> "Main" Then

            Set nextEntry = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "G").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
            Set nextEntry_FTE_quantity = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "K").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
            Set nextEntry_nonrecurring_expenses = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "S").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
            Set nextEntry_initiative_type = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "Q").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
            Set nextEntry_initiative_description = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
            Set nextEntry_economic_benefit = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "AA").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
            Set nextEntry_payroll = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "AI").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
            Set nextEntry_consolidated_social_tax = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "AJ").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
            Set nextEntry_miscellaneous_expenditures = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "AK").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)


            If IsError(Application.Match(wsheet.Name, .Range("G:G"), 0)) Then

                nextEntry.Value = wsheet.Name
                nextEntry_initiative_description.Value = wsheet.Range("K6").Value
                nextEntry_FTE_quantity.Value = wsheet.Range("BH16").Value
                nextEntry_initiative_type.Value = wsheet.Range("K8").Value
                nextEntry_nonrecurring_expenses.Value = wsheet.Range("BH17").Value
                nextEntry_economic_benefit.Value = wsheet.Range("BH15").Value

            End If

        End If
        Debug.Print wsheet.Name
        Next wsheet
    End With


End Sub
```

Comment: What are you actually trying to get?  Payroll,social security and miscellaneous expenditures?  The  multiple Name Measure and Values?  Or both?

Comment: Lookup 3rd column which is VALUES column for payroll, social tax and miscellaneous expenditures and pull them to the main sheet and this needs to be looped through all sheets except Main

Answer (score 0):

From your questions it seems that you have defined named ranges. As I'm aware of your question **[How to copy sheets with certain tab color from one workbook to another?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54361571/how-to-copy-sheets-with-certain-tab-color-from-one-workbook-to-another)** I do believe that you don't have named ranges on your individual sheets.

Below you find some code if you have named ranges (Sub List_NamedRange_Loop).
If you don't have named ranges you can create these named ranges on the individual sheets first (Sub Create_NamedRange).

At the end of this post you find a screenshot of the result I got.

```
Sub List_NamedRange_Loop()

Dim NamedRange As Name
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim PrDebug As Boolean
Dim iCt As Integer

PrDebug = False      '        => Output to Worksheet "Main"
'PrDebug = True      '        => Output to Immediate Window (Ctrl-G in VBE)

'List on sheet "main"
If Not (PrDebug) Then
    On Error Resume Next
    Debug.Print ActiveWorkbook.Name
    Sheets("main").Activate
    If ActiveSheet.Name <> "main" Then
        Worksheets.Add
        ActiveSheet.Name = "main"
    End If
    On Error GoTo 0
    Range("A1:D1000").ClearContents
    Range("A1").Value = "Sheet Name"
    Range("B1").Value = "Named Range"
    Range("C1").Value = "RefersTo"
    Range("D1").Value = "Value (Direct Reference)"
    Range("E1").Value = "Value (Named Reference)"
End If

'We expect all named ranges to be local = defined on the indivdual sheets
'so no need for the below 'workbook loop'

'Loop through each named range in workbook
'  For Each namedrange In ActiveWorkbook.Names
'    Debug.Print namedrange.Name, namedrange.RefersTo
'  Next namedrange

'Loop through each named range scoped to a specific worksheet
    iCt = 0
    For Each ws In Worksheets
        iCt = iCt + 1
        If ws.Names.Count > 0 Then
            If PrDebug Then
                Debug.Print
                Debug.Print ws.Name
            Else
            End If
            For Each NamedRange In ws.Names 'Worksheets("Sheet1").Names
                If PrDebug Then
                    Debug.Print ws.Name, NamedRange.Name, NamedRange.RefersTo
                Else
                    iCt = iCt + 1
                    Range("A1").Offset(iCt, 0).Value = ws.Name
'                    Range("B1").Offset(iCt, 0).Value = Replace(NamedRange.Name, ws.Name & "!", "")
                    If InStr(1, NamedRange.Name, "'") Then
                        Range("B1").Offset(iCt, 0).Value = Replace(NamedRange.Name, "'" & ws.Name & "'!", "")
                    Else
                        Range("B1").Offset(iCt, 0).Value = Replace(NamedRange.Name, ws.Name & "!", "")
                    End If
                    Range("C1").Offset(iCt, 0).Value = "'" & NamedRange.RefersTo
                    Range("D1").Offset(iCt, 0).Value = NamedRange.RefersTo
                    Range("E1").Offset(iCt, 0).Formula = "=" & NamedRange.Name
                    Range("E1").Offset(iCt, 0).Calculate
                End If
            Next NamedRange
        Else
'            iCt = iCt + 1
'            Range("A1").Offset(iCt, 0).Value = ws.Name
'            Range("B1").Offset(iCt, 0).Value = "NO NAMES DEFINED!"
        End If
    Next ws

End Sub
```

If you don't have named ranges you might create them with the code similar to the following:

```
Sub Create_NamedRange()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim foundRange As Range

    For Each ws In Worksheets
        If ws.Name <> "main" Then
            Debug.Print ws.Name
            Set foundRange = ws.Cells.Find(What:="payroll", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt _
                :=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:= _
                True, SearchFormat:=False)
            If Not (foundRange Is Nothing) Then
                Debug.Print "Found: "; ws.Name
                'offset between AR and BH: 16 columns (https://imgur.com/nPYyLbM)
                ws.Names.Add Name:="payroll", RefersTo:=foundRange.Offset(0, 16)
                ws.Names.Add Name:="consolidated_social_tax", RefersTo:=foundRange.Offset(1, 16)
                ws.Names.Add Name:="miscellaneous_expenditures", RefersTo:=foundRange.Offset(2, 16)
            End If
        End If
    Next ws
End Sub
```

[image: screenshot - comparing values and formulas]

Comment: Thank you for your reply! I have Named ranges in individual worksheets. What I want to do is to select these "Assumptions" boxes and name them "Assumption" in each green sheet. Then in my code I just want to select these named ranges and lookup values in the 3rd column.
I tried doing
    nextEntry_payroll.Value = wsheet.Application.VLookup(Range(p).Value, wsheet.Range(r), 3, 0)
but it gives me an error Run-time error '1004': Method 'Range' of object'_Global' failed

Comment: The size of your "assumption" box is constant? Is there anything you need from the "assumption" box? Or do you only need the values "payroll", "consolidated_social_tax" and "miscellaneous_expenditures"? Have you tried the above code?

Comment: The width on the column is constant but depending on the number of variables I would need to pull from this table in future might differ, so is the length of the table. Payroll, cst and me are just most important ones I dont know if I would come up with some more in the future. That's why I'm trying to use lookup function.
As for your code, it's a bit complicated for me since I'm relatively new to VBA and still figuring things out, first programming experience afterall. I would need some time to digest your code

Answer (score 0):

I would use `Range.Find` to locate the cells by keywords and return the values adjacent to them.

```
Sub TestFind()
    Dim colOffset As Long
    Dim wsheet As Worksheet
    colOffset = Columns("BH").Column - Columns("AR").Column - 2 'Two Extra Cells in Merged Range  Adjustment
    For Each wsheet In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        If wsheet.Name <> "Main" Then
            Debug.Print FindValueRelativeToSearch(wsheet.Columns("AR"), "payroll", 0, colOffset)
            Debug.Print FindValueRelativeToSearch(wsheet.Columns("AR"), "social tax", 0, colOffset)
            Debug.Print FindValueRelativeToSearch(wsheet.Columns("AR:AT"), "miscellaneous expenditures", 0, colOffset)
        End If
    Next

End Sub

Function FindValueRelativeToSearch(SearchRange As Range, search As String, rowOffset As Long, colOffset As Long) As Variant
    Dim cell As Range
    Application.FindFormat.MergeCells = True
    With SearchRange
        Set cell = .Find(What:=search, After:=.Cells(1, 1), _
                         LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                         LookAt:=xlWhole, _
                         SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                         SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                         MatchCase:=False, _
                         SearchFormat:=True)
    End With
    cell.Offset(rowOffset, colOffset).Activate
    If cell Is Nothing Then
        Debug.Print "Search not found: FindValueRelativeToSearch()", SearchRange.Address(0, 0, xlA1, True), search
    Else
        FindValueRelativeToSearch = cell.Offset(rowOffset, colOffset).Value
    End If

End Function
```